# OnMyLocationChangeListener Google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps

Eu tenho uma aplicação que funciona como um rastreio de GPS, está funcionando normal, quando o usuario se mexe ele joga no meu servidor a mudança que faz com que todos os aparelhos troquem de lugar o Marker. Porém eu preciso fazer com que a função OnMyLocationChangeListener, funcione mesmo com o aplicativo fechado, pensei em um Service, mas não sei se isso é possível. Alguém sabe se é? Se não for, existe uma forma melhor de se fazer?

Comment: Sim, é possível. Da mesma forma que se conecta com a `GoogleApiClient` na `Activity`, é possível fazer em um `Service`, porém irá usar o `LocationClient` e não o `GoogleMap`. Apenas cuidado com o uso do GPS, não deixe o `Service` ativo sem necessidade, porque GPS gasta muita bateria. Para usar o `LocationClient` de uma olhada em http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html.

Comment: Opa, obrigado, vou tentar usar.

Answer (score 1):

Sim isso é possivel. Você deve declarar um IntentService e usar um BroadCast para comunicar com a app. Você poderá estar sempre com os dados de localização atualizados, mesmo se a app não estiver executando.  [**Aqui**](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) você encontra a melhor forma de fazer isso.